# how to display images in pdf using xhtml2pdf in django

Tags: django, pdf

im working on a django project and i want to generate a pdf file where the information of the user are going to be displayed, the header and the footer must be images, im creating the pdf files using xhtml2pdf library, i've read somewhere that that library does not use "real" css rules. so the image must be in pdf format, i tried to convert it but it's still not displayed.
this is my view:

```
class attestation_travail(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('personnel/attestation_travail.html')
        context = {
            'url': static('images/1.pdf')
        }
        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('personnel/attestation_travail.html', context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            n = random.randint(100, 100000)
            filename = "Attestation_travail_%s.pdf" %n
            content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            download = request.GET.get("download")
            if download:
                content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

and this is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Attestation de travail</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-weight: 200;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .header {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: 100;
                text-align: center;
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: 22px;
                font-weight: 100;
               /* text-align: right;*/
               padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
            }
            .title span {
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .details {
                padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
                text-align: left !important;
                /*margin-left: 40%;*/
            }
            .hrItem {
                border: none;
                height: 1px;
                /* Set the hr color */
                color: #333; /* old IE */
                background-color: #fff; /* Modern Browsers */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <div class='header'>
                <img src="{{ url }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='details'>

            <hr class='hrItem' />
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping I have understood your question well, what I do is create a route that returns me the image like:

```
class MyImage(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
            return HttpResponse(myImageFile, content_type="image/png")
```

In my urls.py file Id have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('myImageUrl',views.MyImage.as_view()),
]
```

Then in my template , Id have:

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/myFullPath/myImageUrl" alt="no trend graph found" style=" width: 100%;z-index: 0;height:185px;">
```

The x-index and height and width stylings are to help the image appear neat.

I hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following line of code in HTML and Django version=2.0 works for me.

`<img src="{{institute_obj.institute_pic.path}}" height="100px">`

Here in src attribute replace with your code

Answer (score 0):

The image needs to be converted to base64.

If you need to transform certain image you need to create a filter in the directory `app/templatetags`. For this example: `img_to_base64.py`

```
from django import template
import base64
import requests

register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def to_base64(url):
    return "data:image/png;base64, " + str(base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content))
```

Now, in the template:

```
{% load img_to_base64 %}
<img src="{{ photo_url|to_base64 }}">
```

[Source](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/388#issuecomment-764512024)

Comment: senquevila, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)